# algorithm to remove unwanted sub-graph in a DAG with switches

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a directed acyclic graph (DAG). Some of its nodes are multiplexers (a switch that can select one of its inputs as output). Before traversing such a graph, the user will set the position in each multiplexer so the path to traverse such a graph can be determined, although the solution may not be unique. I'm thinking of removing all the paths that connect to the multiplexers but not being selected by the multiplexers. I feel that there must be a well-known algorithm to solve such a problem as this sounds like a well-known problem. I don't want to reinvent the wheel and come up with a naive solution if there are already efficient solutions out there to use.

The above problem can be depicted as the following picture:

[image: DAG with multiplexers]

D and E are multiplexers. For example, D can choose to allow A or B to pass to E.

If D select the path B->D->E and E selects the path C->E, then there is no need to keep the path B->D->E and I would only need the path C->E. Is there any well-known algorithm that does this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not start in the opposite direction? Then you can cut out bigger chunks of the graph without having ever to lose time analysing those sub-graphs. So in the image you would start in E, and there cut out D (and thereby A and B).

Comment: @trincot the above is only a simplified example of the type of the graph. I have also thought about starting from backward but I believe there should be a well known algorithm that can solve such a problem.

Comment: Why do you believe that? What is the desired output? You write that you are *"thinking of removing all the paths that connect to the multiplexers*". If you need an output where these paths are removed, then that is what you need to do.

Comment: The desired output is a new graph with all those unwanted paths removed. And that’s what I am asking here. If I know how to do it I wouldn’t post the question in the first place. The reason that I believe there is a well known algorithm exists is because this seems to be a problem commonly encountered in circuit design where the circuit needs to decide which path to go in a graph. And there are lots of other applications which have already solved such a problem.

Comment: If I haven't misunderstood the problem, the solution is trivial. For each multiplexer, replace the multiplexer with a normal node that is connected to the user selected multiplexer branch, which is essentially what you thought of. I don't see why there would be a specialized algorithm to do this.

Comment: @Evil Tak, that will leave me a graph with lots of disconnected sub graphs. Running through such a graph makes no difference to my original graph. But you did suggest a solution to this problem- remove all those disconnected parts after replacing switches will give me what I want. I just wonder if this problem has been well researched and already have efficient solutions.

Comment: @james: Nothing can be asymptotically faster than what you just described.  Basically, delete all but one in-edge to each multiplexer (i.e., leave the "chosen" input edge) and then get rid of every connected component that is not connected to the output.

Comment: The [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3547/ac839d02f6efe3f6f76a8289738a22528442.pdf) does something similar when constructing the failure function. You might be able to do something similar with your DAG.

Comment: Thanks @j_random_hacker I’ll give that a try then

Comment: @Jim Mischel could you plz elaborate a bit more on how that algorithm relates to my question?

Comment: The Aho-Corasick builds a trie, which is a type of DAG. After the trie is built, it goes through the graph and creates a "failure function" for dead ends. You have a DAG that, if I'm reading your question correctly, contains a bunch of dead end nodes. I'm suggesting that you traverse the graph recursively and remove those dead ends. It should be an O(n) operation.